# Проблема с расширением QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlayout, qt6

Суть в следующем, в форме есть QScrollArea, внутри которой есть QWidget. В этот виджет я добавляю динамические фреймы, заполненные некой информацией о контактном лице - ФИО, номер телефона, email, описание.
Выглядит это всё примерно так(снизу):

[image]

Всё выглядит вполне адекватно, однако стоит любое из полей сделать достаточно длинным - допустим, ФИО + описание - так сразу размер QLabel расширяется, переходя все границы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это ладно, ерунда начинается там, когда размер и ФИО и описания довольно длинные - там всё вовсе ломается. Размер QLabel Не ограничивается размерами, выделенными им в Widget'е, они расширяют всю ScrollArea, пряча весь не уместившийся текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже устал комбинировать разные сочетания SizePolicy, как мне ограничить размер либо всей ScrollArea, чтобы она не выходила за рамки, либо же размер самого QLabel, чтобы в случае, если текст в этом лейбле длиннее места, выделенного этому лейблу - он не расширялся, а просто прятал текст.

UPD. Можно добиться "ПРИМЕРНО" нужного мне поведения, если включить эту галочку (опять же, пришел к этому методом тыка) :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой результат после этого действия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, тогда и вся ScrollArea перестает расширяться,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что тоже не является грамотным решением. В общем, выручайте, люди, что нужно сделать, дабы подобрать нужные мне настройки фрейма/виджета/QScrollArea, чтобы текст не вылезал за рамки размера QLabel, обозначенные не текстом внутри, а именно окружающими его факторами.

Вот код самого "обновления" фреймов в зависимости от содержания QList

```
void MainWindow::UpdateNewClientPhones(){
ClearNewClientPhones();
bool mainIsThere = false, notMainIsThere = false;
for(int i = 0; i < NewClientPhones.size(); i+=5){
    
    dynamicFrame *frame = new dynamicFrame(this);
    frame->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    frame->setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(47,49,54);"
                         "color:white;"
                         "border-width:1px;"
                         "border-radius:8px;"
                         "border-color: black;");
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(frame);
    QHBoxLayout *hLay_1 = new QHBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *hLay_2 = new QHBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *hLay_3 = new QHBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *hLay_4 = new QHBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *upperH = new QHBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *downH = new QHBoxLayout();
    QVBoxLayout *vLay = new QVBoxLayout();


    dynamicLabel *icon_fullName = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    icon_fullName->setFixedSize(24,24);
    QPixmap pix_fullName(":/images/images/administrator-24.png");
    icon_fullName->setPixmap(pix_fullName);
    dynamicLabel *fullName = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    fullName->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    fullName->setFont(defaultfont);
    if(NewClientPhones[i+1] != ""){
        fullName->setText(NewClientPhones[i+1]);
        fullName->setToolTip(NewClientPhones[i+1]);
    } else {
        fullName->setText("—");
        fullName->setToolTip("Не указано");
    }
    fullName->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextSelectableByMouse);
    hLay_1->addWidget(icon_fullName); hLay_1->addWidget(fullName);

    dynamicLabel *icon_info = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    icon_info->setFixedSize(24,24);
    QPixmap pix_info(":/images/images/about-24.png");
    icon_info->setPixmap(pix_info);
    dynamicLabel *information = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    information->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    information->setFont(defaultfont);
    if(NewClientPhones[i+2] != ""){
        information->setText(NewClientPhones[i+2]);
        information->setToolTip(NewClientPhones[i+2]);
    } else {
        information->setText("—");
        information->setToolTip("Не указано");
    }
    information->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextSelectableByMouse);
    hLay_2->addWidget(icon_info); hLay_2->addWidget(information);

    upperH->addLayout(hLay_1); upperH->addLayout(hLay_2);
    //fullName->setMinimumWidth(104);
    //QSpacerItem *spacer = new QSpacerItem(80, 20, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

    dynamicLabel *icon_phone = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    icon_phone->setFixedSize(24,24);
    QPixmap pix_phone(":/images/images/phone.png");
    icon_phone->setPixmap(pix_phone);
    dynamicLabel *phone = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    phone->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    phone->setFont(defaultfont);
    if(NewClientPhones[i+3] != ""){
        phone->setText(NewClientPhones[i+3]);
        phone->setToolTip(NewClientPhones[i+3]);
    } else {
        phone->setText("—");
        phone->setToolTip("Не указано");
    }
    phone->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextSelectableByMouse);
    hLay_3->addWidget(icon_phone); hLay_3->addWidget(phone);

    dynamicLabel *icon_email = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    icon_email->setFixedSize(24,24);
    QPixmap pix_email(":/images/images/email.png");
    icon_email->setPixmap(pix_email);
    dynamicLabel *email = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    email->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    email->setFont(defaultfont);
    if(NewClientPhones[i+4] != ""){
        email->setText(NewClientPhones[i+4]);
        email->setToolTip(NewClientPhones[i+4]);
    } else {
        email->setText("—");
        email->setToolTip("Не указано");
    }
    email->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextSelectableByMouse);
    hLay_4->addWidget(icon_email); hLay_4->addWidget(email);

    downH->addLayout(hLay_3); downH->addLayout(hLay_4);
    vLay->addLayout(upperH); vLay->addLayout(downH);

    dynamicButtonMainOrNotMainPhone *button_main = new dynamicButtonMainOrNotMainPhone(frame);
    button_main->setID(QString::number(i));
    button_main->setMainStatus(NewClientPhones[i]);
    button_main->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    button_main->setFixedSize(60,24);
    if(NewClientPhones[i] == "1"){
        button_main->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{color:black;"
                                "border-style: solid;"
                                "border-width:1px;"
                                "border-radius:3px;"
                                "border-color: black;"
                                "max-width:60px;"
                                "max-height:24px;"
                                "min-width:60px;"
                                "min-height:24px;"
                                "color:black;"
                                "background-color:rgb(5, 255, 26);"
                                "}"

                                "QPushButton:hover{ color:black;"
                                "border-style: solid;"
                                "border-width:1px;"
                                "border-radius:3px;"
                                "border-color: black;"
                                "max-width:60px;"
                                "max-height:24px;"
                                "min-width:60px;"
                                "min-height:24px;"
                                "color:black;"
                                "background-color:rgb(5, 156, 16);"
                                "}");
    } else {
        button_main->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{color:black;"
                                "border-style: solid;"
                                "border-width:1px;"
                                "border-radius:3px;"
                                "border-color: black;"
                                "max-width:60px;"
                                "max-height:24px;"
                                "min-width:60px;"
                                "min-height:24px;"
                                "color:black;"
                                "background-color:rgb(255, 0 , 0);"
                                "}"

                                "QPushButton:hover{ color:black;"
                                "border-style: solid;"
                                "border-width:1px;"
                                "border-radius:3px;"
                                "border-color: black;"
                                "max-width:60px;"
                                "max-height:24px;"
                                "min-width:60px;"
                                "min-height:24px;"
                                "color:black;"
                                "background-color:rgb(145, 0, 0);"
                                "}");
    }
    button_main->setText("Основной");
    connect(button_main, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setMainOrNotMainPhone()));


    DynamicButton_Delete_clientPhone *button_x = new DynamicButton_Delete_clientPhone(frame);
    button_x->setID(QString::number(i));
    button_x->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    button_x->setFixedSize(24,24);
    button_x->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{color:black;"
                            "border-style: solid;"
                            "border-width:1px;"
                            "border-radius:3px;"
                            "border-color: black;"
                            "max-width:24px;"
                            "max-height:24px;"
                            "min-width:24px;"
                            "min-height:24px;"
                            "color:black;"
                            "background-color:rgb(255, 0 , 0);"
                            "}"

                            "QPushButton:hover{ color:black;"
                            "border-style: solid;"
                            "border-width:1px;"
                            "border-radius:3px;"
                            "border-color: black;"
                            "max-width:24px;"
                            "max-height:24px;"
                            "min-width:24px;"
                            "min-height:24px;"
                            "color:black;"
                            "background-color:rgb(145, 0, 0);"
                            "}");
    button_x->setText("X");
    connect(button_x, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(deleteDynamicButton_deleteClientsPhone()));
    lay->addLayout(vLay); lay->addWidget(button_main); lay->addWidget(button_x);
    frame->setLayout(lay);
    if(NewClientPhones[i] == "1"){
        if(mainIsThere == false){
            mainIsThere = true;
        }
        ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(frame);
    } else if(NewClientPhones[i] == "0"){
        if(notMainIsThere == false){
            notMainIsThere = true;
        }
        ui->verticalLayout_6->addWidget(frame);
    }
}
if(!mainIsThere){
    dynamicFrame *frame = new dynamicFrame(this);
    frame->setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(47,49,54);"
                         "color:white;"
                         "border-width:1px;"
                         "border-radius:8px;"
                         "border-color: black;");
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(frame);
    dynamicLabel *isClear = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    isClear->setText("Пусто");
    isClear->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    isClear->setFont(defaultfont);
    lay->addStretch();
    lay->addWidget(isClear);
    lay->addStretch();
    frame->setLayout(lay);
    ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(frame);
}
if(!notMainIsThere){
    dynamicFrame *frame = new dynamicFrame(this);
    frame->setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(47,49,54);"
                         "color:white;"
                         "border-width:1px;"
                         "border-radius:8px;"
                         "border-color: black;");
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(frame);
    dynamicLabel *isClear = new dynamicLabel(frame);
    isClear->setText("Пусто");
    isClear->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    isClear->setFont(defaultfont);
    lay->addStretch();
    lay->addWidget(isClear);
    lay->addStretch();
    frame->setLayout(lay);
    ui->verticalLayout_6->addWidget(frame);
}
}
```

Comment: Чтоб получилось «хорошо», то см. гугл по запросу `QLabel Ellision`. Если кратко, то идея в том, чтобы добавлять в QLabel сокращённый текст, но придётся наследовать `QLabel`, чтобы ресайз на уменьшение работал... зато будет нормальное сокращение с многоточей, а не просто обрубленный текст... Если хочется отделаться малой кровью и решить всё через sizePolicy виджетов, то выложи [mcve] с формой «на поиграться»...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо за наводку на Ellision - пока что-то тяжко даётся. Я добавил код самого обновления фреймов в зависимости от содержания QList

Comment: @Fat-Zer попробовал сделать что-то подобное:  QFontMetrics metrics(fullName->font());
        QString elidedText = metrics.elidedText(fullName->text(), Qt::ElideRight, fullName->width());
        fullName->setText(elidedText); Но проблема в том, что fullname->width() постоянно возвращает одно и то же значение, независимо от размера окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить `QLabel` на `QLineEdit` в котором установите (в QtCreator в таблице свойств объекта):

- readOnly - установить галочку
- frame - снять галочку
- background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); Прозрачный фон

В таком виде `QLineEdit` не будет отличаться от `QLabel`, но любой, вылезающий за края текст, будет обрезаться. Чтобы строка отображалась с начала ("обрезался" хвост), надо после ее добавления в `QLineEdit` вызвать, либо метод `setCursorPosition(0)`, или `home(false)`

Кроме того, если вы "укладываете" виджеты подряд, друг за другом, то рекомендую использовать [layoutStretch](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qboxlayout.html#setStretch) (в таблице свойств лейаута). Например, если у вас 2 виджета в лейауте, то вы можете задать им весовые коэффициенты заполнения пространства (важно именно соотношение), например, таким образом `1,3`, что означает второй будет больше в 3 раза, чем первый, `5,2` - первый относится ко второму как 5 к 2-м и так далее

Comment: Спасибо, в целом, как минимум как временное решение, тема с QLineEdit работает, только проблема в том, что в случае длинного текста теперь, в ЛайнЭдите пишет текст с конца, а не с начала. В итоге если написать "Очень-очень длинное-длинное описание", то в лайнэдите будет написано "инное-длинное описание"

Comment: @Mainquestion после вставки строки вызовите функцию QLineEdit::setCursorPosition(0) https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#cursorPosition-prop и текст будет виден с начала

Comment: Или функцию `QLineEdit::home(false)`